# Как сделать так, чтобы можно было вписать только цифры и плюс вначале строки? Регулярки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, redux-form

В интут можно было вписать только «+» в начале и цифры . Никаких других символов. 
Какой парсер нужно написать? Делаю через `redux-form`

Вот тут чищу строку от всех плюсов, кроме того что вначале строки идет

```
const mobile = value => value.replace(/[()\s-]/g,'').replace(/(?!^)\+/g, '');
```

Чтобы были цифры нужно применить еще ?

```
value.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

То есть получается

```
const mobile = value => value.replace(/[()\s-]/g, '').replace(/(?!^)\+/g, ‘’).replace(/\D/g, '');
```

А чтобы еще исключать первый плюс и давать возможность его вписать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
value.replace(/[^\d^\+]/g,'').replace(/\+/g,function(a,b,c){
    if(b!=0)return '';
    else return a;
  });
```

Comment: а можно пояснить что такое a b c

Comment: и еще линтер ругается на unnesessary escape character /+.

Comment: @werty это 3 аргумента, называть можно по разному, в данном случае
а - найденый символ или подстрока
b - позиция
c - вся строка